# Add Auto Play to Tilted Content Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, joomla3.0, autoplay

I have been trying to add autoplay to a tilted content slider that I have loaded on Joomla. I found a similar post and took their code, put in a Jquery file which I have been able to successfully load but it is now causing an error in the main .js file for the slider. I have figured that is probably because the main code is not numbering the slides but just assigning a nav button to each slide which then needs to be clicked to load the specific slide. Here is the pertinent part of the main .js file for the current navigation.

```
TiltSlider.prototype._init = function() {
    this._addNavigation();
    this._initEvents();
}
// add the navigation to the DOM
TiltSlider.prototype._addNavigation = function() {
    // add nav "dots"
    this.nav = document.createElement( 'nav' )
    var inner = '';
    for( var i = 0; i < this.itemsCount; ++i ) {
        inner += i === 0 ? '<span class="current"></span>' : '<span></span>';
    }
    this.nav.innerHTML = inner;
    this.el.appendChild( this.nav );
    this.navDots = [].slice.call( this.nav.children );
}

TiltSlider.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var self = this;
    // show a new item when clicking the navigation "dots"
    this.navDots.forEach( function( dot, idx ) {
        dot.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
            if( idx !== self.current ) {
                self._showItem( idx );
            }
        } );
    } );
}
```

I am a hopeless coder!  I know enough to be able to start understanding what it is doing but no idea how to actually write something to do what I want!!  I am really hoping that someone will be able to show me what to add so that I can get this to run automatically.  The file I tried prior was:

```
    ( function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    new TiltSlider(document.getElementById( 'vina-tilted-content-slideshow'           
    ));               
    window.setInterval(function(){              
        $('nav>.current').next().trigger('click');
        if($('nav > .current').next().index() == '-1'){
            $('nav > span').trigger('click');
        }               
    }, 10000);

    }); })(jQuery);
```

This called the following error in a line in the main.js that was related to the el.appendchild call above.
m.Callbacks.jjquery.min.js:2 m.Callbacks.k.fireWithjquery.min.js:2 m.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2 J

Would greatly appreciate any help!
Thanks.